# Distinguish between comment and docstring

Tags: color, listings, python

I'm writing a paper an I want to insert some Python code. The problem is that I want to have green docstrings and grey comments. How can I do it?

I know how to change the color of comments, however I'm not able to distinguish between a comment and a docstring.

So far, my attempt is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\definecolor{cgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{cgray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{cpurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{cwhite}{rgb}{1,1,1}

\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
    backgroundcolor=\color{cwhite},   
    commentstyle=\color{cgreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{cpurple},
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{cgray},
    stringstyle=\color{cpurple},
    basicstyle=\footnotesize,
    breakatwhitespace=false,         
    breaklines=true,                 
    captionpos=b,                    
    keepspaces=true,                 
    numbers=left,                    
    numbersep=5pt,                  
    showspaces=false,                
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,                  
    tabsize=2
}

\lstset{style=mystyle,language=Python}  

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
def inici():
    """This must be green"""
    tauler=[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]] #And this must be gray
    return tauler 
\end{lstlisting}


\end{document}
```

With my examples, all (comments and docstrings) are green.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I added a couple of lines to make the example compilable and the picture.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that the xcolor package predefines most common colors. The default purple is very red and the default green is very yellow, but the default white is exactly white and the default gray is basically the same as your gray so I suggest using the built in ones.

Anyways, you can use the `moredelim` key to specify delimiters like `"""`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\definecolor{mygreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{mypurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}

\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{  
    commentstyle=\color{gray},
    keywordstyle=\color{mypurple},
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
    basicstyle=\footnotesize,                
    keepspaces=true,                 
    numbers=left,                    
    numbersep=5pt,                                
    moredelim=**[s][\color{mygreen}]{"""}{"""}
}


\lstset{language=Python,style=mystyle}  

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
def inici():
    """This must be green"""
    tauler=[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]] #And this must be gray
    return tauler 
\end{lstlisting}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Still not working, it complies (and I undestand more or less the idea of what you're doing), however there's no color change

Comment: Have you tried compiling exactly my sample code? When I run the above code using pdflatex, it works perfectly.

Comment: Solved, my fault

Answer (score 0):

The extension `piton` directly detects the doc-strings, that is to say the strings that are specified by `"""` (cf. PEP 257). So, it's possible to specify different styles for strings, comments and doc-strings.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{piton}

\begin{document}

\SetPitonStyle
  {
    Comment = \color{gray} ,
    String.Doc = \color{DarkGreen}
  }

\begin{Piton}
def inici():
    """This is a doc-string"""
    tauler=[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]] #This is a comment
    return """This is a long string which is not a doc-string"""
\end{Piton}

\end{document}
```

The extension `piton` requires LuaLaTeX but no exterior program (you don't need `--shell-escape`).

[image: Output of the above code]